# How to activate Bootstrap 4 modal by clicking a button in the first page, that redirects you to a second page with modal activated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For my project, I want to implement a [modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/). I am using **Bootstrap 4**. The modal should work as following:

- When I press the button in the first .html page, the button should redirect me to a second .html page, meanwhile open a modal in that second .html page as a welcoming.

So the modal in that case is like a welcoming message as a popup box.

To make things clear. The button "code" is in the first .html file, the modal "code" is in the second .html file.

Button:

```
<a href="index.html"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block text-uppercase" type="button"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLogin">Prijavi se</button></a>
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLoginLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLoginLabel">Pozdravljeni!</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Dobrodošli v digitalnem gradbenem delovnem listu.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Nadaljuj</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried everything. from id's, to trying to relocate the code, to trying to find another solution, with JavaScript, but no luck so far.

Comment: Can you share the jquery/javscript code you've used?

Comment: Hi @HowardE. This "code" did not require any jquery/javascript code. Bootstrap 4 does everything for you. But the solution to the problem might be or probably is using jquery/javascript, but I didn't had any luck with it so far. I hope i answered your question.

Comment: Yes... Your answer required javascript.

Comment: Hi @HowardE. I tried to use JavaScript to find the solution, but it was not working, so I tried different things, mentioned in the post above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A click on your `<a>` cannot open a modal in another page that is about to be opened. Instead, what you do is you slightly modify the href of your `<a>`, for example: `<a href="index.html/welcome"></a>`.

Then, in your JS (that is being loaded with `index.html`) you can check if there is a 'welcome' in your URL when the user navigates to the page. If there is, you trigger the modal to show. It would look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("welcome") > -1) {
        $("#modalLogin").modal("show");
    }
});
```

This way, when the user navigates to `index.html` the modal doesn't show, but if the user clicks on your button, the modal will be displayed because the URL will contain `welcome`.